# Large number division is too slow using bignumber.js in node.js

Tags: node.js, bignum

I am using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-number to perform division of two large numbers:

My function has the following code:

```
var x = new BigNumber(val);
var y = new BigNumber(100000000);
return x.dividedBy(y).toNumber();
```

This code is called 100 times on my machine and it takes about 10 seconds for it to execute. It runs much faster on another machine, however we have limited resources in the cloud and I would want to optimize this.

What can I do to optimize this?
I am using the `classical for` loop to do the 100 iterations.

Comment: Are the operands & result integers or floating point?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with *integers*, there is a built-in `BigInt` type in JavaScript which will give you the best performance:

```js
let x = BigInt(val);
let y = 100000000n; // BigInt literals end in "n"
return Number(x / y);
```

Comment: I measured the speed, it's more or less the same.

Comment: Unfortunately that's the best speed you can achieve then. If you think it's unreasonably slow, send a bug report to V8.